# C# Bullet list in PARAM section of code documentation

Tags: c#

For a function parameter, I want to use a list of options in the code documentation.

For the `<summary>` tag, this is no problem ([Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/list)). But how do I make a bullet list for a `<param>` tag? The example below doesn't create a list in the quickview window while programming:

```
<param name="Type list">
<list type= "bullet">
<item><description>Item description</description></item>
</list>
</param>
```

Comment: Can you not have a <list>...</list> block within <param>...</param> ?

Comment: I've tried but without succes. I've put an example in the question.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This works fine.

I tried this code:

```
public class Program
{
    /// <summary>The summary</summary>
    /// <param name="args">
    /// The command-line arguments.
    /// <list type="bullet">
    /// <item><description>Item 1</description></item>
    /// <item><description>Item 2</description></item>
    /// <item><description>Item 3</description></item>
    /// </list>
    /// </param>

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
}
```

Then I used Sandcastle to produce a help file which looks like this:

[image: Output Documentation]

As you can see, the bulleted list appears correctly for the parameter.

This is how Resharper shows the tooltip:

[image: Resharper shows a bulleted list]

Comment: But does this also show a list while programming in the menu which apears?

Comment: @Quispie Oh, you didn't say that you were expecting it to appear as a bulleted list in the tooltip! Well, the tooltip does list all the items, just not as a bulleted list. However, Resharper DOES show it as a bulleted list.

Comment: I know, I changed it just now, thanks for your response. I will take a look at Resharper.

Comment: @Quispie I can't recommend Resharper highly enough. (Also, I've added a screenshot of how it shows the XML doc.)

Answer (score 0):

Bullet list didn't work for me, perhaps because I want to add it for a class property. Use `<para>` for that, like this:

```
public class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Main comment.
    /// <para>List 1 :</para>
    /// <para>- Item 1</para>
    /// <para>- Item 2</para>
    /// <para>- Item 3</para>
    /// <para>- Item..n</para>       
    /// </summary>
    public string property1 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Swagger in .NET 6 (possibly earlier), use standard HTML list tags:

```
/// <summary>
/// ...
/// </summary>
/// <param name="...">_some_text_like_"Available Values:"
///    <ul>
///       <li>item 1</li>
///       <li>item 2</li>
///       <li>item 3</li>
///       <li>...</li>
///    </ul>
/// </param>
```

*Note: Indentation not required.*

Answer (score -1):

If you user xml doc with Swagger, it will ignore  tag, instead you should use "-"

```
/// my list:
/// option 1
/// option 2
///
/// other staff
```